# I have used AssetImage to upload an image into main.dart, although I'm not getting error, image is not appearing. somebody pls help me

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

//this is my debug console.. I'm not able to use assst image. here is my code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
            body: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 100,
                  child: const CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundImage: AssetImage('imagesananth.JPG'),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            )));
  }
}
```

My debug console says this.

Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1
Parameter format not correct -
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
W/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate( 1646): A splash screen was provided to Flutter, but this is deprecated. See flutter.dev/go/android-splash-migration for migration steps.
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:63032/t0OqF0A8X0U=/ws

Comment: in which folder you have kept the image?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `assets` to your image path:

```dart
CircleAvatar(backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/imagesananth.JPG')),
```

Also, take a look at your file extension. If it ends with .jpg, but not .JPG you have to use .jpg in your path. It is case-sensitive.

If you put the `imagesananth.jpg` to some folder inside assets(for example images) than you have to add this path to `pubspec.yaml`:

```
assets:
    - assets/images/
```

and use it:

```dart
CircleAvatar(backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/images/imagesananth.jpg')),
```